# Angular 12 upgrade: [Violation] 'load' handler took 238ms

Tags: angular, angular-upgrade

I have upgraded the version of the angular application to version 12 using the below.

```
npx @angular/cli@12 update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@12
npx @angular/cli@12 update @angular/material@12
ng update
```

I am using leaflet 1.7.1 for interactive maps.
But while running the application I am getting below warnings in the console and my leaflet map is loading properly but not clickable(zoom in/out, pop up) until I resize the window. These warnings were not there before the upgrade. This is a very weird issue and I am not getting the exact reason behind the map issue.

```
[Violation] 'load' handler took 248ms zone.js:1607 
[Violation] 'load' handler took 423ms zone.js:2536 
[Violation] 'requestAnimationFrame' handler took 559ms 
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 43ms zone.js:2536 
[Violation] 'requestAnimationFrame' handler took 56ms
```